# Same sample have two different data in a conference and journal paper (experimental research)

Tags: phd, research-process, journals, conference

I published two papers one is the conference and other is journal paper. The problem is that For same same sample I have to measure same characteristics at two different times. Time gap between  measurements is almost one year. Both measurements are not completely similar. Actually both the study was different so that for extension of work I need to take measurements again. I think Results may be different because of long gap of measurements. It could not get same environment. Is it wrong? Will I be caught? I am fearing so much. It’s matter of my career. Please suggest what I can do. Because it’s inferring with conference paper (less valued) then it will not affect journal paper? Journal paper is more important for me.
FYI : both the papers are published!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135649/discussion-on-question-by-ansu-same-sample-have-two-different-data-in-a-conferen).

Answer (score 1):

By the same "sample" I assume you mean the same subjects. With a time gap of a year it is completely natural that the results of data collection would be different. Change happens, especially if the subjects are, for example, human. And more so if the experimental conditions themselves changed. Even for quite simple questionnaire data, one can expect different answers from the same subjects over time.

There is nothing to fear from such a situation, but there might be something to explain. That might make the second paper even more valuable.

But it is worth spending some effort to figure out why the data are different and reporting that. Don't forget to cite the earlier paper, of course.

Comment: "But it is worth spending some effort to figure out why the data are different" Exactly that, and then there is no risk of getting "caught", as OP fears. However, unfortunately, in the experimental sciences the underlying reasons for such problems sometimes remain unknown, despite the best efforts to find them.

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't cite the paper! Will paper be retracted if i caught! I am in fear. pls give enlightenment in this issue.

Comment: Why couldn't you cite the other paper?

Comment: I find its irrelevant to cite!

Comment: I thought its irrelevant bca both the study was different!

Comment: @Ansu It involves the same type of measurements in the same sample just a year apart and you think it is irrelevant? I find that very hard to believe.

Comment: Its okay but what is the solution. bcs I just reported what i got! just with minor changes!

Comment: If the papers are both published then it is what it is. But it would, I think, only be a problem if someone thinks there is misconduct. But you should probably have cited the early paper in the later one. If you can file a correction to do so then it might be worth it.

Comment: Sorry I can't!  will conference paper be considered as serious evidence to retract journal paper! if someone claim!